# Rails on Jenkins -- Do I need RVM installed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jenkins, rvm, jenkins-plugins

Fast question.

I am setting up Jenkin CI for my Rails project. Almost every online installation guide ask for RVM to be installed along with Jenkin's RVM Plugin. While I use `chruby` for Ruby versioning instead of RVM, I only need Ruby 2.0 for my project.

Is RVM required to run a Rail app on Jenkins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I have seen, no. It would be helpful, as with the RVM plugin for Jenkins, I believe you can manage the gemset that you use for that Jenkins project through Jenkins. But my suggestion is try it and if it doesn't work, go the RVM route. Without using RVM, I believe Jenkins will just use the default ruby without having the option to change from within Jenkins.

Comment: the rvm plugin has a nice trick - put `.` as the ruby name and it will use ruby from project `.ruby-version` or `.rvmrc`

Comment: Thank you for replying. Even though I have chruby installed on my base box, I still installed rvm for the jenkins user. I ran across many errors attempting to use chruby and it was super easy to setup rvm.

Comment: No problem. Hopefully you will get used to using rvm; I find it an extremely easy tool to use.